# assign value from two input to a single input type hidden

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of first input or second input and assign it to a hidden input type. When the value updates from the above default value.

HTML

```
 <input id="amount2" name="s_value6" type="number" value="48">
 <input id="amount3" name="s_value11" type="number" value="500">
 <input id="mak" type ="hidden" name="distance" value="">
```

jQuery

```
if(mafsForm.find("#amount3").val().length !== 0 || mafsForm.find("#amount2").val().length !== 0) {
      var s_value11 = mafsForm.find("#amount3").val(); 
      var s_value6 = mafsForm.find("#amount2").val(); 
      var dist = $('#mak').val($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: I see typo in your code what is `makkah` or is it `mak` ? Also , what is `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: its mak just miss here

Comment: by `$(this).val()` I am trying to assign the above two values

Comment: simply do `$('#mak').val(s_value11+", "+s_value6 )` this will set value as comma separated.

Comment: I need one of them not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for. To test this, remove 'hidden' from the hidden input field. Then change the value of any of the first two input boxes. On every change, 3rd input box will be updated with latest value. Below code only shows latest value from the last updated input box

```
$("#amount2, #amount3").change(function(){
    var changedVal = $(this).val();
    if(changedVal !== '0'){
      $("#mak").val(changedVal);  
    }
  });
```

Comment: The most easy way. Thanks for your help bro!

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example of pure javascript ...

```html
<input id="amount2" name="s_value6" type="number" value="48">
<input id="amount3" name="s_value11" type="number" value="500">
<input id="mak" type="hidden" name="distance" value="">

<script>
  var amnt2 = document.getElementById("amount2");
  var amnt3 = document.getElementById("amount3");
  var mak = document.getElementById("mak");

  amnt2.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    setValue(this.value);
  });

  amnt3.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    setValue(this.value);
  });

  function setValue(num) {
    mak.value = num;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I have put the script in footer and html code in my template but its not working you can check on my site [link](https://www.ashshariyah.com/travel/umrah-packages)

Comment: I had a look, you have multiple "amount2" fields in the page, change names ? Make sure all the names are unique.

Comment: Please check it now thanks for your time I can give you access if you have time

Comment: i had another look - the problem is you have 2 "amount2"  - remove the one then it should work

Comment: your solution is to remove the 2 input fields - you already have sliders with those id's  - I did that and your page worked perfectly.

Comment: I change the ids but still no luck

Comment: can I give you access to do it for me please ?

Comment: yes sure, send me an email to: antonpublic70 @ gmail . com, with a user name and password.

Comment: i had another look and sorry to say, but you changed the wrong stuff ... send me an email or something and I will give you instructions to fix - i tried pasting it here but it's too long.

Comment: I sent email please check

Answer (score 0):

The `mafsForm` variable was not assigned a selector in your code, so instead of `mafsForm.find(selector).val()` I wrote `$(selector).val()`. Also, I used the `parseInt()` method to convert the value to a number for summation. You can easily adapt this code for yourself.

```js
$('#amount2, #amount3').on('change', function() {

  var s_value11 = $("#amount3").val(); 
  var s_value6 = $("#amount2").val(); 

  if(s_value11.length !== 0 || s_value6.length !== 0) { 
        value_sum = parseInt(s_value11) + parseInt(s_value6);     
        console.log(value_sum);
        var dist = $('#mak').val(value_sum);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="amount2" name="s_value6" type="number" value="48">
<input id="amount3" name="s_value11" type="number" value="500">
<input id="mak" type ="hidden" name="distance" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need one of them either first or second

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that **$(this)** is referencing the window object. Here's a working solution:

```js
var mafsForm = $('#mafsForm');
var dist;
if(mafsForm.find("#amount3").val().length !== 0 || mafsForm.find("#amount2").val().length !== 0) {
    var s_value11 = mafsForm.find("#amount3").val(); 
    var s_value6 = mafsForm.find("#amount2").val(); 
    dist = $('#mak').val(s_value11);
};

console.log(dist.val());

// Now if you want to update the value of the hidden value when changing the value of a filed you can do this
mafsForm.find("#amount3").on('input', function() {
    var s_value11 = mafsForm.find("#amount3").val(); 
    dist = $('#mak').val(s_value11);
    console.log(dist.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id = "mafsForm">
     <input id="amount2" name="s_value6" type="number" value="48">
     <input id="amount3" name="s_value11" type="number" value="500">
     <input id="mak" type ="hidden" name="distance" value="">   
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and time but I want to change the hidden field by both not only one